# Multi-line find and replace across multiple files on linux

Tags: linux, html, sed, find-and-replace

I have:

- Old Google analytics tracking code `oldcode.txt`
- New Google analytics tracking code `newcode.txt`
- 100+ html files `*.html` in one directory

Is it possible to replace former with latter in all html files?

Comment: Perhaps in the future it would make more sense for you to source the "Google_analytics.js" in each header so in the future you only need to adjust one file (obviously this doesn't work in all cases, and yours may be one of them). Looks like the answer below may work, albeit inefficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the `oldcode.txt` contains this:

```
I am the old code
```

And the `newcode.txt` looks like this:

```
I am the newwwwwwwwww
```

Then here is what you need to do:

```
for htmlFile in `ls *.html`; do
    cat $htmlFile | sed -i .orig 's/I am the old code/I am the newwwwwwwwww/g' > tmpCopy.html
done
```

Comment: The old and the new both contain multiple lines of text. Will this still work?

Comment: @FullDecent: You can enter "multiline mode" in `sed` with the `N` operator, e.g. like this: `printf 'hi\nho\n' | sed -e 'N; s/i\nh/ell/'`. This will print "`hello`". Make sure you do many test cases and escape your special characters correctly before running it for real. And have backups, as always. If you don't want to do it with `sed`, Perl or `awk` are two other popular text processing alternatives. But `sed` should work. Paste a specific example in your question (but anonymize personal details) for a more specific answer.

Comment: You can save a few steps here if you remove the `cp`, `mv` and `rf` codes. Instead, use `sed -i.orig ...`, that automatically creates a backup called `filename.txt.orig` and writes updates to the original. Just to elimate a few steps

Comment: @nerdwaller - great point... did not know that! Have modified my answer

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee I just stumbled on it recently, always nice to save some typing :)